# Query RDS tables over time

Tags: mariadb

I have a question regarding which database is appropriate for the following task since I currently use MariaDB but I believe that the following requirements can be fulfilled better by a different solution.

Currently for this relational database data is recived for each day of the year. The data is not timestamped it is just related to the day it was received and loaded to the database. However, I would now like to not remove the data for each day but instead keep it and be able to query over data received over multiple days. I have tried to make schema for each day with the same tables but this does not seem to be the correct solution.

For example on Wednesday i receive the following tables:

- A
- B
- C

and Thursday

- A
- B
- C

The data in the tables is not timestamped but has been received on a certain day and therefore related to that day. I would like to query the data of the tables across days.

What I want is a database where I can store this data which is not timestamped but that is received each day and be able to query it by the day it was received. How would this kind of database be called?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is a database where I can store this data which is not timestamped but that is received each day and be able to query it by the day it was received. How would this kind of database be called?

This kind of database would be called "impossible". You cannot query something that's not stored in the database, so no timestamp -- no query by day.

However, you can easily solve your problem by defining the tables, into which you are loading data, such that each has an extra column of the `DATE` data type, populated automatically by the value of `CURRENT_DATE` when a row is inserted.

```
create table foo (
  something int, 
  something_else text, 
  added_on date default (current_date));

insert into foo (something, something_else) values (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar');
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QGFXe26U)